# PY8583 Python Library Building Incorrect ISO8583 Bitmap

Tags: bitmap, iso8583

The Python library py8583 [github link](https://github.com/alxnik/py8583) seems to be building the incorrect bitmap for the Iso8583 bitmap.

I've followed the examples shown in the included IsoHost.py file, however even when testing with a fairly simple message creation the bitmap still seems to be way off. I'm expecting a 64-length field of 0's and 1's that correspond to field being enabled.

This is what I've been using to conduct the test. If you run the example you'll see that the bitmap simply is not what it should be. (Note: you have to decode the HEX to binary in order to see the real bitmap being sent.)

```
IsoPacket = Iso8583(None, IsoSpec1987ASCII())
IsoPacket.MTI("0100")

# Merchant ID/Code
IsoPacket.Field(33, 1)
IsoPacket.FieldData(33, 'TESTABCD')

# Router serial number (taken from Store table)
IsoPacket.Field(41, 1)
IsoPacket.FieldData(41, 'F406C431')

# Add NPC's proprietary header and message length
IsoPacket = struct.pack("!I", len(IsoPacket)) + IsoPacket

return IsoPacket
```

I'm expecting to see bitmap have all 0's except for positions 33 and 41, if you run the example you'll see it's turning other fields "on" that aren't event listed in the code.

Is there someone with more Python (or py8583) experience that can see if I'm just completely missing something?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but may help others in troubleshooting. The correct message should be

```
0100000000008080000008TESTABCDF406C431
```

Where the primary bitmap is

```
0000000080800000
```

As you can see ISO8583 bitmap is not represented as a 64-bit field of 1s and 0s, but rather as a hex char string. This hex char string is basically a 64-bit field, but it's never transmitted as such.

To add, some specifications define primary bitmap as Binary Coded Decimal field. In this case this message will looks like this.

```
0100\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x80\x00\x0008TESTABCDF406C431
```

Where primary bitmap is

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x80\x00\x00
```

The assumptions

- All fields are ASCII
- Primary bitmap is either ASCII or BCD
- Field 33 is LLVAR, max 11 bytes long
- Field 41 is fixed, 8 bytes long